# Conservation condition in rotating cylindrical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, navier-stokes

Is this correct?

Cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta,z,t)$:

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} +\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r\rho V_r)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\rho V_\theta)+\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (\rho V_z)=0$$

Rotating cylindrical coordinates $(r^{\prime}, \theta^{\prime},z^{\prime},t^{\prime})$, rotation is about the z-axis:

$$r^{\prime}=r,$$

$$\theta^{\prime}=\theta-\omega t,$$

$$z^{\prime}=z,$$

$$t^{\prime}=t,$$

$$V_r^{\prime}=V_r,$$

$$V_\theta^{\prime}=V_{\theta} - \omega t,$$

$$V_z^{\prime}=V_z,$$

thus $\frac{\partial }{\partial t} \mbox{     now becomes   } \frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\omega\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}$, thus the conservation condition in rotating cylindrical coordinates becomes

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}-\omega \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \theta}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r\rho V_r)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} (\rho (V_\theta-\omega r))+\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (\rho V_z)=0$$

(all primes have been omitted)

Is this correct (please show why yes or no)?

Comment: Are you also supposed to transform the radial and cylindrical velocity components to the primed system?

Comment: Note that questions of the form "Is this right?" tend to be poor fits for this site because the answer, yes or no, is too short to be a valid answer. Consider making the question more open ended so a proper answer can be written.